# Upwards sloping AC lines leaking with sprayfoam and caulk

Tags: hvac, insulation, waterproofing, siding, caulking

Related to [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/282791/82408), the installer came and applied a silicone caulk around all the individual lines (see pictures below), but it still leaks (though to a lesser degree). Given that now spray foam and silicone are already applied, 1) what more can I do to completely fix the leak? 2) I plan to spray foam from inside the basement for winter proofing (pictures below), but I assume this wouldn't be good for waterproofing purposes, as the wooden wall would still get wet?

I understand they should ideally slope downwards, but these are quite rigid lines for refrigerant, drain, and power coming from two second-floor rooms, running along the siding, and entering the basement (to connect with a branch box).

This is an indoor view ([full-sized image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUeWr.jpg)):

[image: Indoor View]

Caulking behind the line hide ([full-sized image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxtjG.jpg)):

[image: Caulk behind line hide]

The different lines rub against each other tightly (red circled areas), where there is no spray foam and it is difficult to apply caulk. (full-sized images [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbC2Z.jpg) and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kM4P6.jpg)). The two black cables are electric and communication lines.

[image: Front view]
[image: Side view]

A [zoom out view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4kpq.jpg):

[image: Zoom out view]

Comment: I use the phrase "double down on stupid" with self-deprecation once in a while. I was reminded of the expression when I saw that silicone caulk sprayed all over like that. I didn't realize that you could buy silicone caulk in an aerosol can. You said that there's electric mixed in with that mess? Is there a conduit out of frame or something? Could you zoom out some? I think the scope of this fix includes more than just tips on how to use spray foam.

Comment: @popham It's not from a silicone aerosol can.. The installer actually smeared it on to that effect by hand... I've edited the post to indicate that the black cables are electric and communication lines, as well as adding a zoom-out picture. There is the line hide but no conduit through the basement wall.

Comment: In spite of the enclosures, water is running down the lines to infiltrate? Or is it infiltrating at the space between the siding and the back of the bracket(s) (red circle in the second photo)? You're sure that the water isn't condensation from the refrigeration lines?

Comment: Usual solution is a drip loop before entering the wall...

Comment: Tie a string as far down each line as you can, and try to encourage the water to run down the dangle.  (And cover what you can to discourage as much water as you can from running down the lines.)

Comment: @popham The leak would occur after raining without AC even running, so it's not from condensation. According to the installer, the line hide is just for aesthetics, not waterproofing. We are not entirely how water is going in, so they caulked both behind and inside the enclosure. But definitely there is evidence of water inside the enclosure and water running along the lines and dripping at the lowest point inside the house.

Comment: @keshlam Drip loops are probably not very practical for this bundle of very thick and stiff lines.

Comment: .... true, @P.B, but you wouldn't bend it as a bundle; you'd bend each one separately and then bundle. Still might not be a viable answer in this case, but if not I'm not sure how to retrofit adequate gasketing.

Comment: Is the current leaking occuring during actual weather events? Or are you spraying it with a hose or something for testing purposes?

Comment: @popham It was all during actual raining. Initially with only the spray foam, there would be water pooling on the basement floor after a heavy rain. After the additional silicone caulk, water only drips. It's clearly very difficult to create a good seal around all the individual lines.

Comment: It might be time to call that point "good as it gets" and move on to more fruitful positions. The wall penetration is probably stiffening everything at that location substantially. If you go a few feet above, then can you easily open the space between each line? If so, then I would open the bundle there to get a gasket of silicone caulk between everything and around its perimeter. Then I would take a sheet of plastic and zip tie it around this still-wet gasket in a manner where there's no space for pooling at its top--you want to "shingle" the gasket over the top edge of the plastic.

Comment: The bottom of this plastic is now a drip edge that I can shape to channel water to a drainage point. There are drainage holes at the bottom of that plastic enclosure, right?

Comment: I would prefer butyl tape for sealing between electrical insulation, but it probably wouldn't work for the refrigerator lines. That tinfoil is part of loose insulation around the refrigerator lines, right? And water hasn't snuck _in_ there somewhere, right?

Comment: Thanks -- you gave me a number of ideas to try. Yes, the tinfoil is the outer skin of  insulation sleeve around the refrigerant lines and there is a drainage hole in the line hide. I'm not sure if water has gotten into the insulation sleeve or not though.